# "the retailer would get twelve or more" is this the final price?

Tags: phrase-usage

I’d like to ask about the sentence from Six Napoleons by Conan Doyle.

> Their wholesale price was six shillings, but the retailer would get
> twelve or more.

Does this mean the retailer sells this product (sculpture) for 18 shillings?  6 plus 12, which is retailer’s gain.

Or the retailer sells the sculpture 12 for each?

If it was “put” as in “but the retailer would put twelve or more”, I would take it the final price being 12 or more, but “get” is used here. “get” means “take, gain, grasp..” right?  So I thought this “twelve or more” to be the retailer’s profit and end customers have to buy this at 18 shillings, I don’t know. Could someone tell me?  Thanks.

Comment: It's ambiguous. There is no way of telling from the sentence alone which is meant. I believe it's much more common, however, for *get* in this context to refer to the sale price. Twelve shillings would be the *gross* amount of money received, and six shillings the *net* amount of money earned—the profit (after accounting for the six shillings already spent on purchasing it from the wholesaler). This also makes sense given that it seems to be a comparative sentence, comparing the wholesale price to the retail price. (The problem comes from the different wording used.)

Comment: 12 or more not 18 or more. 'Get' = 'sell for'.

Comment: @JasonBassford, you are muddying the waters. This sentence is completely unambiguous in British English (and surely in Canadian English too?), and means that the retailer would sell the item for 12 shillings or more.

Comment: @TonyK I don't find it "completely unambiguous" at all. I've heard people say *get* when they're talking about their profit rather than their sale price. I qualified my comment with the sale price being "much more common," which is true. But it's not *always* the intended meaning. *Get* is often used in the same sense as *take in*. And people will say, "Oh, after expenses, I *got* X."

Comment: @JasonBassford: *after expenses, I **made** X.* In practice there no ambiguity in OP's context unless you're actually ***looking*** for a "perverse" interpretation.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Most analysis of English (*Can this mean anything else? Is there only one meaning?*) is exactly about so-called perverse interpretations. It's especially true of people who don't speak it natively and are trying to understand how it *is* commonly used, not how it *could* be used. Any comprehensive answer to questions like this should be complete—or at least not ignore uncommon variations.

Comment: I can't see that. You represent maybe 1 in 100 native speakers who are prepared to *consider* that perverse interpretation (absent any clarifying additional text, such as ***after expenses**, I got X / the retailer would get twelve or more **on top of that***). But in practice no native speaker would normally ***intend*** that perverse meaning without including those "necessary" clues, so I really don't see how you're helping people *learn* English by requiring them to recognize a possibility that never actually arises in practice.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  A possible answer to such a person (which just paraphrases what I already said in my initial comment): "You are right. According to the syntax it *is* ambiguous. [Meaning that you've understood how words work.]  It *can* be interpreted in different ways. However, *common use* of the words in this context normally means this one thing. But what could be done with the words actually used to make the meaning less ambiguous? Here is a possibility." If you don't ***explain*** to people what things mean and how to use words, then you aren't helping them learn at all.

Comment: Hmm. It seems to me that from your perspective, *every* English utterance is inherently ambiguous. Which on some rarified metaphysical plane is unquestionably true, but that wouldn't normally be helpful. And don't forget that almost nobody ever got explicitly told much about such ambiguities when they were learning their ***own*** language. Whatever - I don't think we're ever likely to see eye-to-eye on this one.

Comment: Not ambiguous is the U.S., either.

Comment: This is clear to me. They could get upwards of 12/s.